# WebGL Compute Shader and VBO/UBO's

Tags: webgl

AFAIK is the compute shader model very limited in WebGL. The documentation on this is even less. I have a hard time to find any answers to my questions.

Is there a possibility to execute a compute shader on one or multiple VBO/UBO's and alter their values?

Comment: Compute Shaders are not available in WebGL nor WebGL2

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That is why I couldn't find some. I hope they will be implemented soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: On April 9 2019, the Khronos group released the [a draft standard for compute shaders in WebGL 2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0-compute/).

Original answer:

In [this press release](https://www.khronos.org/blog/webgl-2.0-arrives), the Khronos group stated that they are working on an extension to WebGL 2 to allow for compute shaders:

> What’s next? An extension to WebGL 2.0 providing compute shader support is under development, which will bring many leading-edge graphics algorithms to the web. Khronos is also beginning work on the next generation of WebGL, to bring the enhanced performance of the new generation of explicit 3D APIs to the web. Stay tuned for more news!

Your best bet is to wait about a year or two for it to happen on a limited number of GPU + browser combination.

Comment: I think it will be good for the webgl community. tnx for sharing.

Comment: @Huy Nguyen, the link is dead

Comment: @snb link fixed.

Comment: @HuyNguyen That was fast!

Comment: Given the work going into [gpuweb](https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb) I'm not sure if we'll see compute capability added to WebGL. Interestingly WebCL was a thing, announced back in 2011, but was never adopted by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

**2022 UPDATE**

It has been declared [here](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/2.0-compute/) (in red) that the WebGL 2.0 Compute specification has instead been moved into the new WebGPU spec and is deprecated for WebGL 2.0.

WebGPU has nowhere near global coverage across browsers yet, whereas WebGL 2.0 reached global coverage as of Feb 2022. WebGL 2.0 Compute is implemented only in Google Chrome (Windows, Linux) and Microsoft Edge Insider Channels and will not be implemented elsewhere.

This is obviously a severe limitation for those wanting compute capability on the web. But it is still possible to do informal compute using other methods, such as [using regular graphics shaders + the expanded input and output buffer functionalities supplied by WebGL 2.0](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl2-whats-new.html).

I would recommend Amanda Ghassaei's [gpu-io](https://github.com/amandaghassaei/gpu-io) for this. It does all the work for you in wrapping regular GL calls to give compute capability that "just works" (in either WebGL or WebGL 2.0).

Comment: Great, thanks for your contribution. I'll have a look.